# How get item from a listView Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I get a item from a listView 2 items , I am using to fill the listView a database of queries but there do not know how to do that to get the name of the item ?

```
    from = new String[]{manager.CN_NAME,manager.CN_CREDITS};
    to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2};
    manager = new DataBaseManager(this);
    listaMateria = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    cursor = manager.cargarCursorMateria();
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,cursor,from,to,0);
    listaMateria.setAdapter(adapter);

    listaMateria.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
            String a = Integer.toString(to[position]);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), a, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also get the cursor for that row.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                 View view, int position, long id) {
          Cursor cursor = (Cursor)adapter.getItem(position);
          String value = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("column_name"))
}
```